# Border-radius delay on hover

Tags: html, css, web, hover

Border-radius takes a half-second or so to load on hover, so square div is shown before it corrects to the corrected rounded shape.

Code works correctly in Firefox, but does not work on Safari or Chrome.

Here's the link. Hover over any of the 3 circles to see the bug in either Safari or Chrome.

http://test.kaitlynjoy.com/border-radius-bug/#websection

Why is there this delay?

Thanks!

Comment: Provide your code snippet what you are trying

Comment: Please create a JSFiddle of some sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting the border radius of your div to 100% when hidden as well?

Just playing around with your code in the web inspector, I set the elements to have a border radius, and the square glitch was resolved. Try this:

```
.webcircle,
.mask {

  border-radius: 100%;

}
```

The circle is ever so slightly cutoff when the enlarge effect gets triggered on hover. If you set overflow: visible to the parent element, it should be functioning the way you'd like and be ready for finishing details.